# Postgresql how to change numrange to numeric column type

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table

```
ALTER TABLE tb_economic_parameter 
    ALTER COLUMN c_economic_parameter_value TYPE numeric 
          USING c_economic_parameter_value::numeric ;
```

I get this error:

> Query failed: ERROR: cannot cast type numrange to numeric

How can I change it?

Comment: Well how do you expect to cast a range to a single value? What numeric result would you expect for `numrange(1, 10)`?

Comment: I have deleted all the data. so changing column type should be straight forward.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE t ALTER COLUMN n TYPE numeric USING NULL`, that tells it how to cast the existing type to your new type.

Comment: it gives syntax error at numeric

Comment: Post the full command you're using. The one I posted above worked for me on an empty test table with one column (n) of type numrange.

Comment: Sorry I figured out, now its running using ALTER TABLE tb_economic_parameter ALTER COLUMN c_economic_parameter_value  TYPE numeric USING NULL;